# Asking questions about game events, with specific in-game situation

Tags: discussion, questions

I have a question about a specific in-game situation, and ask about the reaction from a well known party?

To elaborate, we need to offload a Deathguard with intact Gene-seed, but we're uncertain about what might happen if we turn him over to the Inquisition, given the circumstances of his coming into our possession.

My uncertainty for asking this question stems from the possible lengthy explanation that comes before, as well as the possible outcomes that may stem from it.

Comment: It's very hard to figure out what you're asking here. Are you asking about citations from universe fiction to establish precedent?

Comment: Not sure. I want to know what the Inquisition would do, knowing the situation form which we obtained him (a derelict space hulk that was redacted from all records, people died even hearing about the place)

Answer (score 5):

## You can ask about setting information

Questions about game settings are totally on-topic here. (The only exception is if the game setting is primarily from a non-game source, like Westeros, in which case you're better off asking at [scifi.se](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) and might see the question closed here, depending.) If you want to ask what can be known about the reactions of a public-figure NPC in an RPG setting, we can try to answer that, though it's possible there is insufficient information published to be able to answer certain questions.

However, that's only if you're asking about the setting in an idealized, canonical sense. That's the sort of thing that a GM might ask, when seeking raw material to inform their creative process when deciding how/whether/what to do in a game they're running.

## But you can't (usefully) ask what will happen in *your* game

The GM is not bound by our conclusions about a setting when it comes to *their* vision of the setting in a game that *they* are running.

When you're a player, and trying to gather information for decision-making in-game, you can't take what we say, or even written canon, as true. Assuming that information you gather outside of the game is true for the *specific* game reality that your character lives in is just asking to be proved wrong.

---

If you honestly want to know more about a setting, ask away. If you want to find out information to give your character an edge or help you make a decision, you can still ask, but take the answers with a grain of salt, especially if it's not basic common knowledge within the setting or you're not sure whether your GM has other ideas.

If there is any sliver of doubt that your GM might contradict setting information—and when it comes to the thoughts and choices of NPCs, this is very rarely dictated strictly (or even vaguely!) to the GM by the setting material—you're **far** better off engaging in that kind of discussion with your GM, or simply having the character directly engage in the appropriate research.